# Unset local key binding in `magit-status`

Tags: key-bindings, magit, hooks

I want to remove magit local key binding for `C-w` (to use global one).
But can't find which hook I can use for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key magit-status-mode-map "\C-w" nil)))
```

Use <kbd>C-h m</kbd> to view the doc for the current major mode and <kbd>C-s hook</kbd> to search for hook, then you should know which hook to use.

The following is another way without using hook:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'magit
  (define-key magit-status-mode-map "\C-w" nil))
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove Magit's binding use:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'magit
  (define-key magit-status-mode-map "\C-w" nil))
```

This delays changing the key binding until the keymap you want to change actually exists. You should never use a major-mode hook to change a key binding, because that would re-establish the (un)binding every time a buffer is created that uses the same major-mode.

But in this particular case there is no reason to restore the default binding. Magit's binding for <kbd>C-w</kbd>,`magit-copy-section-value`, does shadow the global binding, `kill-region`. But that doesn't matter because `kill-region` only works when the region is active, and `magit-copy-section-value` does fall back to do the same thing as `kill-region` does, when the region is active. So effectively Magit does *not* shadow the global binding, it augments it.